# woocommerce pagination not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

On my locally hosted site is the woocommerce pagination not working properly.
When I use `http://localhost/sample-post/` the second page is a wrong one. I'm landing on an attachment page instead of the second product page.

When using `http://localhost/?p=123` it works ok.
Anyone an idea?

Is it because I'm working locally and will it not be on a remote server? I've read something about that. Need confirmation.

**EDIT**

Went worse.....
I have to translate the site in different languages using WPML. When using the default permalinks WPML complains. When using another structure (see above) and in WPML the setting for a different folder for each language I got pages with no result (except for a message from woocommerce that no products were found.

**EDIT 2, February 18th, 2015**

I start to wonder if it is even possible to set the WooCommerce shop page as the Front page. The support team of WooCommerce is puzzled as well and are wondering too if it is possible. I hope someone has experience with it or an example of a site on which it works.

Please, can anyone help me out here... I'm struggling now for a long time and I'm not able to solve this myself.

Answer (score 1):

your permalinks settings need adjusting. in wp-admin go to settings>permalinks>common settings, and set "per post." check your product permalink base as well.

Comment: Thanks you for your reaction. As stated, changing the settings of the permalinks takes me to the wrong page (an attachment page, as stated in the question). The only setting the woocommerce pagination works properly (from one product page to the next) is in the default setting. Don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Having the same issue- I am tempted to add CSS to switch off the pagination then write some PHP to generate new pagination with ?p=123 etc... Or find some way to modify the links with a regular expression and filter... but my WordPress is a bit to weak...

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function for correct woocommerce pagination. please use this function inside the function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_pagination_args',  'rocket_woo_pagination' );
function rocket_woo_pagination( $args ) {
  $args['prev_text'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>';
  $args['next_text'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>';
  return $args;
}
```